# Using resource id in android programming

Tags: android, android-layout

Why do we use resource id's for the widgets in android programming, when not every widget needs a resource ID ? 
Do I need to create individual id's for every widget or can I use just one id for similar widgets ?

Comment: The resource ids are created automagically when you create an instance of a View and assign it an id with `android:id="@+id/someId"`. It is needed for obtaining that View from the layout with `findViewById(R.id.someId);`

Comment: If you want multiple widgets to extend some similar functionality, just have their response call some sort of method. The reason we assign ID's is to distinguish two widgets in a layout. Some widgets don't need ID's (for instance a linearlayout) because the user is not always directly interacting with that layout.

Comment: @Tukajo that last part is misleading. There are plenty of reasons to give  a `ViewGroup` (such as a ` LinearLayout`) an id. *" because the user is never directly interacting with that layout"* the "never" is untrue. I've needed to often.

Comment: I know there are reasons to do so, I am saying that you don't always necessarily have to. I modified the wording a bit.

Comment: Yeah I caught that, my bad. Rephrased it.

Comment: Android generates a resource ID for the entire layout and for each string, but it does not generate IDs for the individual widgets in my activity.xml file. So i after reading the discussion I think that I should only define ID's for the widgets that needs to be refer by my java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we use resource id's for the widgets in android programming, when not every widget needs a resource ID ?

You only need `android:id` attributes for those widgets that need to be referenced by something else, mostly:

- your Java code
- Java code that you are inheriting (e.g., `ListActivity` and `ListFragment` need a `ListView` with `@android:id/list`)
- other widgets in the same `RelativeLayout`

You are welcome to put `android:id` attributes on everything, and drag-and-drop GUI builders (e.g., Android Studio) will tend to do that.

> can I use just one id for similar widgets ?

Not usually. The ID needs to be sufficiently unique, by which I mean that when you go to try to find the widget, when you call `findViewById()` (on the activity or some ancestor `ViewGroup`), that you will get a unique result.

Comment: Thank You. You explanation was very clear. It makes more sense now.